# Confused about when exactly I should malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I know if I am inputting a string into a pointer variable I would malloc that based on the size of the input received.

But what if I am using a pointer variable for the use in [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)? For example if I want the pointer to point to the the character "z" in a string.

```
char *pointer;

pointer=strchr(string,'z');
```

Would I need to malloc pointer? Or is it not needed?

Comment: Most string functions, like e.g. [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) returns pointer to a position *in* the string you pass to the function. In the case of you example, `strchr` returns a pointer to somewhere inside `string`, or `NULL`.

Comment: Please read about `malloc()` answering this with yes or no will confuse you more.

Comment: `strchr` returns a pointer like `string + x` where `x` is the offset of the first occurrence `'z'` in `string`. It's a pointer to an existing, valid memory address. No need to allocate that memory twice. Mind you, if `string` is a `const char *`, `pointer` will point to read-only memory, using `pointer` to change the values in there will cause errors. In that case, you'll want to copy the string to writable memory, either on stack or heap, but even then: I'd probably use `strdup` for that

Comment: Learn about the difference between a pointer and what it points to (the pointee). Before you can dereference a pointer, you need to point it at something. That's all.

Comment: Also think about it like this: When you assign the pointer returned by `malloc` to your variable `pointer`, then the value of `pointer` is the address of the newly allocated memory. If you then *reassign* the pointer to point somewhere else, you loose the original pointer, and will have a memory leak. If you have an integer variable, e.g. `int i`, and assign a value to it, lets say `5`. Then you do `i = 42`, you loose the original value of `i`. It's the same with pointer variables.

Comment: And finally, if you are not sure, always *read a reference*, it will tell you what it returned. [This is a good reference for the C language](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and its standard functions.

Comment: C does not have a string type. It is all convention. And "inputting a string **into** a pointer" is always wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to allocate any memory here . Strchr function returns a pointer to the first occurence of a char in a string if it exists. If a given string deos not contain a char then a null will be returned.

You need to allocate memory only if you want to create something new, that has not been created yet. In this case the input string exists and a pointer will point to a position within this string.

Answer (score 0):

`strchr` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character in the C string.

It's pointing to a memory location which is having the character searching  in the C string, so no need to allocate new memory using `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

Using `malloc()` to allocate space for a pointer and then reassigning the pointer is wrong. You can't even perform pointer arithmetic on it because then you can't free it. You allocate memory and then use that memory, the pointer will then contain the address to that memory, if you overwrite that address then your program will not have a possible way to access that memory not even to free it. Then the allocated memory is useless and there is no point in allocating memory for this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use malloc if you need the system to provide you memory to store data. For example, if you want to store a string you should allocate memory for it

```
char* s = malloc(10);
strcpy(s, "something");
```

If you only need a pointer that points to something that already is in memory you mustn't allocate it, in your case the `strchr` function return a pointer that points to the position in memory where is the char `c` in the string `s`

```
char* c;
c = strchr(s, 'm');
```